# how to pass array data to view without routing to view and then using value in view?

Tags: laravel-8

**controller**

```
    \\\ #returns data from cardiohelp
public static function getMonitorTerapiahome($id){
    $dl= new DataLayer;
    $terapia=$dl->getTerapiaById($id);
    $dati_ven=$dl->getDatiVenCHByCardiohelpId($terapia->cardiohelp->id);
    $dati_art=$dl->getDatiArtCHByCardiohelpId($terapia->cardiohelp->id);
    $reports=$dl->getReportByTherapyId($id);

   # return ['dati_art'=>$dati_art];
    return compact('dati_art');
    #return compact('dati_ven','dati_art'))->with('therapy',$terapia)->with('reports',$reports);
}\\\
```

**this is blade.php**

*already mentiond  use\App\Http\Controllers\TherapyController; in view *

```
    \\\<tbody>
            @foreach($terapieList as $terapia)
            
            <tr>
                <td>{{$terapia->patient->firstname}} {{$terapia->patient->lastname}}</td>
                <td>{{$terapia->start_date}}</td>
```

**here i call  method from controller to get back array data and i get Array to string conversion error here**

```
                <?php echo   TherapyController::getMonitorTerapiahome($terapia->id ); ?>
                @foreach(dati_art as $da)
                <td>{{$da}}</td>
                @endforeach
            </tr>
            @endforeach

        </tbody>\\\
```

how can i solve this??
thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you just return the data included in the view from the controller?

Comment: how can i do that ?? i am new to laravel, can u please help by correction or some example please!!!

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Sure, I will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can pass data to your view from your controller:

```php
// MyController.php

public function myView(Request $request)
{
    $id = ...; // get your id
    $datiArt = getMonitorTerapiahome($id);

    return view('my-view')->with('dati_art', $datiArt);
}
```

Then in your view you can access the variables passed to the view like so:

```php
// my-view.blade.php

@foreach($dati_art as $entry)
   <span>The key is: {{ $entry['key'] }}</span>
  // ...
@endforeach
```

Check the Laravel documentation regarding [this topic](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views#passing-data-to-views). Is very easy to find guides in there.